# Call a webservice in asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net

How can I calling a webservice not written by me from asp.net ajax. What's the latest and best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX is not the preferred library any more. Use jQuery instead which also supports [jsonp](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) which is what you will need to call cross-domain web services from the client.

Answer (score 2):

Call the Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy invoke Method

[Details here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/clientreference/Sys.Net/WebServiceProxyClass/WebServiceProxyInvokeMethod.aspx)